# getting result in nested function

Tags: typescript, imodeljs

Please tell me, how can i get result from **function go()**
I  getting error Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

```
export const Block: React.FC<iModel> = () => {

    const go = (imodel: IModelConnection) => {


        const executeQuery = async (query: string) => {
            const rows = []
            for await (const row of imodel.query(query)) rows.push(row)
            return rows

        }

        const getAllCamerasData = async (): Promise<CompositionItemQueryRow[]> => {
            const query = "select ca.ecinstanceid as id, ca.link as cameralink, pho.origin as coordinates from DgnCustomItemTypes_Camera. CameraElementAspect ca join BisCore. ElementOwnsMultiAspects ema on ca.ecinstanceid=ema.targetecinstanceid join generic.physicalobject pho on ema.sourceecinstanceid=pho.ecinstanceid"
            const rows = await executeQuery(query)
            // console.log(rows)
            return rows as CompositionItemQueryRow[]
        }
        return getAllCamerasData()
    }
let camsDat= go()
```

what argument should i pas?
if i passed
`let camsDat=go(imodel)` <--- i have an error **Cannot find name 'imodel'.**

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you omitting some important portions of your code?

- You defined the `go` function to take one argument but passed zero; this is the explanation for your `Expected 1 arguments` error.
- The only variable named `imodel` you have defined is the argument to your `go` function, which is inaccessible when you are assigning to `camsDat`; this explains your `Cannot find name 'imodel'` error.